# How to write sql query for the following

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table - fu_plan_user (id_plan_user,id_user, id_plan, valid_from, valid_to, ...)
table - fu_user (id_user, name, company....)
table - fu_plan (id_plan, name, duration, ...)
```

This is the table structure somewhat.

I want to produce a list of accounts that have a close(valid_to) date which is the end of a month(30th day) and this date should be in the future, like grater than todays date (NOW()). The name of the company should not contain "trial" word.

The result should contain the following fields

```
id_user, name (from table fu_plan), company (from table fu_user), valid_to (from table fu_plan_user)
```

Something like this 
Raw Query (not correct)

```
SELECT usr.id_user, payplan.name, usr.foretag, planUser.da_valid_to
from fu_plan_user planUser, fu_user usr, fu_plan payplan left join
     fu_user usr
     on planUser.id_user=usr.id_user
 where planUser.da_valid_to > now() and
       planUser.da_valid_to >= DATEADD(d, -30, getdate()) ;
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but you are using SQL Server syntax.  You have a massive `cross join`, and you are mixing implicit and explicit `join` syntaxes.  Fix your query and question to be more reasonable.

Comment: I have mentioned it is an incorrect raw form of query. I don't know how to write the query to get the desired result, thats why i have posted the question.  I wrote the query just to give the idea what i want.

Comment: There is something that i don't understand, valid_to date should be greater than todays and in the same month?

Comment: the whole date (valid_to) should be in the future, valid_to > NOW(). The field valid_to stores the date and time, but only those in the future which have last day of the month, like 30th maybe if there is no way to find the last day on the basis of month. Did i explain it fairly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your explanation and only if your database is MySQL, i suggest to use this query:

```
SELECT user.id_user, plan.name, user.company, pbyu.valid_to 
FROM fu_plan_user AS fbyu
    JOIN fu_user AS user
        ON user.id_user = fbyu.id_user 
    JOIN fu_plan AS plan
        ON plan.id_plan = fbyu.id_plan
WHERE pbyu.valid_to > NOW()
    AND LAST_DAY(pbyu.valid_to) = pbyu.valid_to
    AND  user.company NOT LIKE '%trial%';
```

If company isn't only lowercase values, you should use LOWER().
LAST_DAY() function will get the last day from month of valid_to date.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want except a bit modification needed to be made in the where clause WHERE payplan.da_valid_to > NOW() AND LAST_DAY(payplan.da_valid_to) <> date(payplan.da_valid_to) AND user.foretag NOT LIKE '%trial%';

Comment: fbyu replace with payplan